# WordPress change div content using post type and select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin for WordPress that creates a custom post type. A widget is also created that the user can put on the site. The widget wants to list the title of each post in a drop-down select box. When the selected title is changes, the content from the relative post wants to be populated into a div below the select box in the widget.

I have created the post type and widget. The widget is successfully creating the drop-down menu. I am having difficulty with updating the div with the relative content. I initially tried to do this by running through the PHP post loop and add all content to an array however realised that this would be too cumbersome. I'm looking at AJAX as my best solution however I have no experience with this and have been unable to find a useful example.

```
<select id="optionToggle">
    <option value="default">Select a option</option>
    <option value="196">Option 1</option>
    <option value="197">Option 2</option>
    <option value="198">Option 3</option>
    <option value="199">Option 4</option>
    <option value="201">Option 5</option>
</select>
<div class="content"></div>
```

The above is what I am currently constructing with the value been the post ID and Option # been the post title. I have a javascript function that listens to when #optionToggle is changed and it then grabs the value. From what I have heard, it appears that WordPress has a integrated AJAX feature that can grab the content from a given post ID without re-loading the page however I am unable to figure this out.

Has anybody had any experience with this that may be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way .

1. Fire an AJAX request with some action, say "YOUR_AJAX_ACTION_NAME". Pass the Post ID in parameter. ( under the change event handler )
2. You need to add action in your functions.php file

   add_action("wp_ajax_YOUR_AJAX_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME");

   function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(){
   //Your code over here 
   //get the Post ID from the ajax request .
   //From Post ID, get post content.
   //echo the content.
   }
3. In you js file, in the AJAX response handler, write jQuery code to update the content of required DIV.

I hope you can code it yourself now.

Here is the code you can use.

Code for your "Select" change event handler

```
var ajax_data = {
                action: 'YOUR_AJAX_ACTION_NAME',
                post_id: jQuery("#optionToggle").val();
        };

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, ajax_data, function( response ) {

    jQuery("#YOUR-DIV-ID").html( response );
});
```

Add code to functions.php file

```
add_action("wp_ajax_YOUR_AJAX_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME");

function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(){
    if( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && $_POST['post_id'] ){
        $content_post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );
        $content = $content_post->post_content;
        echo $content;
        die();
    }
}
```

If in any case u want non-logged in users to do AJAX, you can add

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_YOUR_AJAX_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME");
```

You can get to know more about it over here : http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins